What measures can silence squeaks from wood scraping over rubber?
I have dealt with annoying noise from wood/rubber friction, and suspect I will see the same problem many more times. Noise gets annoying, part is replaced, synthetic rubber elasticizer evaporates, noise is back.
I have now two times replaced the lower seal on my windows, and am now hitting the problem on a part of my bed frame as well.

Stuffing paper or felt between the (already rather tight) surfaces could not meaningfully reduce the noise, and was not up to the task of handling friction under heavy load anyway and starts to crumble.
I have tried introducing a generous amount of petroleum jelly (medical, not industrial lubricant, still close enough I assume) - that to my surprise resulted in increased noise.

Any more other generic approach to rubber/wood friction that I should try before simply eliminating relevant parts?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

(Edited to de-emphasize the specific application and increase applicability to arbitrary woodworking projects in response comment announcing off-topic vote.)

Arbitrary woodworking questions might be more at home in the Woodworking.SE stack.

Pretty sure woodworking isn’t the appropriate stack.

I think this is an XY Problem. Instead of trying to eliminate the resulting sounds of parts moving against each other, you should be asking about how to prevent the parts from moving in the first place.

Per some web-searching, talcum powder can reduce squeaking on old wood floors. It may help for your bed parts.

Yeah, I'd think baby powder (corn starch) or graphite powder would work well.

I'll try that, and probably revisit the PTFE idea as well.. some of the products even specifically claim suitability for wood surfaces.
